# What is "duplicate in when" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I write code like bellow:

```
when(month){
        1 or 7 -> arrHoangDao = arrayListOf("Tý", "Sửu", "Tỵ", "Mùi")
        2 or 8 -> arrHoangDao = arrayListOf("Dần", "Mão", "Mùi", "Dậu")
        3 or 9 -> arrHoangDao = arrayListOf("Thìn", "Tỵ", "Dậu", "Hợi")
        4 or 10 -> arrHoangDao = arrayListOf("Ngọ", "Mùi", "Sửu", "Dậu")
        5 or 11 -> arrHoangDao = arrayListOf("Thân", "Dậu", "Sửu", "Mão")
        /* 6 or 12 is duplicate */
        6 or 12 -> arrHoangDao = arrayListOf("Tuất", "Hợi", "Mão", "Tị")
    }
```

I get the message is "duplicate in when". What does it mean?

Comment: use `,` instead of `or`

Comment: right, can you tell for me about it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're using [bitwise OR](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/or.html) with `or`. This means that `1 or 7` evaluates to 7 and `4 or 10` evaluates to 14. `6 or 12` also happens to evaluate to 14, hence the compiler tells you it is a duplicate.

Solution: use `,` instead of `or`. See more on how to use when statements [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html).

Comment: I understand , vs or -- but why is "duplicate in when" a warning and not an error message?  Seems like it's always a coding error.

Comment: @pforhan not sure, you would have to ask the kotlin team why they designed it to be a warning